# Sublimerge won't compare to other branch

Tags: git, sublimetext2, diff

I'm having trouble with Sublimerge and comparing to another branch. When I type ctrl+alt+d and choose "Compare to Other Branch" I get a list of garbled branches.

[image: Garbled Branch Names]

If I choose any, like master, which is the one I'd like to diff with, I get an error message.

[image]

Comment: What does `git config --get color.ui` say at the command line?  Does it say `true`?  It should probably be `auto`.  FWIW, those are ANSI escape sequences making it into the branch names... they're added when git is trying to produce colorized output.  Sublimerge should probably be running the commands with color turned off though.

Comment: My color.ui setting was set to always, so I set it to auto. I then restarted sublime and ran into this issue (https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/212). Upon updating my git_command variable "/Users/[me]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Git/Git.sublime-settings" to "/usr/local/git/bin/git" and opening Sublime again, it worked! So everything is happy now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a predefined custom comparison which, fortunately, you can edit and make it working properly. Go to Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublimerge -> Custom Comparisons - Default and find there "Compare to Other Branch…". Then add `--color=never` to the executed command, just like this:

```
"command": "{config:git_executable_path} branch --color=never"
```

this should fix your problem :)

Comment: I like the idea of this but I haven't been able to try it yet. When I edited my config back to color.ui=always so I could try your solution I got exit code 127 when trying to use sublimerge. Not sure what that's about.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the `"command"` to the following:

```
"command": "{config:git_executable_path} -c color.ui=false branch"
```

Let me know which one works for you